# how use limit and fill() in same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i would to use both limit and fill in same array

```
var array = new Array(4).fill({});
var limit = 4;
```

if have some dynamic records it may be vary but i need only 4 records to display
For example:
eg-1
records = 20
it should display only first 8 recorsds in array
output

```
[{record 1},{record 2},{record 3},{record 4}]
```

eg-2:
records =2;
it should display those 2 and the rest 6 index should fill with {}
output

```
[{record 1},{record 2},{},{}]
```

so how can i achieve this?

Comment: You can use `array#slice`. Also, can you update the question with sample input.

Comment: I'd use a `for` loop that iterates over the records you have (or stops at the 4th record). Only when it's finished apply the `.fill({})` method

Comment: @HassanImam yes i have used array.slice(0,limit); so that i get the number of records equal to limit but question is if i have less number of records in array than limit the rest to fields should get filled by `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the generated array with your `limit`, if it is less, add new array to the generated array using `Array.concat()`. Generate the array using `Array.from()`.

```js
var obj = [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    limit = 4,
    index = 4,
    arr = obj.slice(index, index+limit),
    newArr = arr.length < limit ? arr.concat(Array.from({length: limit - arr.length }, _ => ({}))) : arr;
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
function limitArr(arr, limit) {
let newArr = arr.map((item, index, key) => {
    if (limit >= index) {
        return item;
    } else {
        return {};
    }
});
return newArr;
```

}